# Sharepoint 2013 REST-API: get global propertybag value

Tags: rest, properties

on **farm** level we have stored several values in propertybag.

As far as I've understood the [REST Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860569.aspx) there is no way to get that values because the AllProperties endpoint is on web level.

So what to do?

- transfer the properties to all webs?
- defining a managed metadata and use the search-endpoint?

It appears that those solutions will end up having the same data on multiple places.
So where to store these atomic properties and being able to read it via REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for an On Premise solution (which I guess it has to be), you can deploy a [Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521581(v=office.14).aspx) to give access to these properties on your client side interfaces.

If you are thinking of making changes to make it cloud friendly, you can try your idea with the Managed MetaData service and term set's custom properties. I don't know if you can query custom properties using the [SP.Taxonomy.js](http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/accessing-taxonomy-term-store-with-jsom/) but can be looked in to - not sure how far that'll go as a Best Practice.

Another alternative is move everything over to a Site Collection/Sub site that exists for storing Configuration Information - I've used this in some projects and it worked out very well

Comment: yapp, own web service or properties on site collection would be possible. I think I turn to site collection although of the multiple data question. Thanks.

Comment: I like the separate site collection idea because you give users an interface to change and view the configuration